# Xamarin.Forms Use Local Variable in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile

Let's say I have a variable in my .cs file called **number** , I want to set a text of a label in my xaml page to the value of **number**. How can I do that? I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540182/xamarin-local-variable-in-xaml-cs-and-printing-through-the-xaml-file) but it did not help me. am I missing something?

cs:

```
public partial class OrdersPage : ContentPage
{
   
    public string number = Methods.GetMessage("number");
    public OrdersPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }
    private async void Init()
    {
        this.BindingContext = this;
        ....

}
```

xaml:

```
<Label FontSize="Subtitle">
 <Label.FormattedText>
      <FormattedString>
           <Span Text="{Binding number}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
           <Span Text=": " FontAttributes="Bold"/>
           <Span Text="{Binding PickupNo}" TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Static static:Constants.PRIMARY_COLOR}}"/>
       </FormattedString>
 </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: P.S: I tried to use string number {get; set;} but id did not work also

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  `public string number` is public but it is not a C# property

Comment: @Jason so what's the solution?

Comment: make it a **public property**.

Comment: public string number
        {
            get
            {
                return Methods.GetMessage("number");
            }
        }  @Jason did not work

Comment: then you are doing something else wrong.  Have you tried hardcoding the value of the property?  This will tell you if the binding is working or if there is something else wrong.

Comment: @Jason ok I think I know the problem, I am using this binding in a collection view which is binded to an itemsource. So I think it's searching for a property of the itemSource called "number" which  does not exist. what is the solution in this case?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the rest of your code looks like, but my dummy example can maybe help you to figure out what you need to do.
Since you mentioned in the comments that you have `CollectionView`, I guess it looks something like this:

XAML:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Label FontSize="Subtitle">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="{Binding number}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Span Text=": " FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                <Span Text="{Binding PickupNo}"/>
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
             </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

In your .cs file you should have MyCollection of MyItem, defined something like this:

```
public partial class OrdersPage : ContentPage
{
   
        public class MyItem
        {
            public string number { get { return Methods.GetString("number"); } }
            public string PickupNo { get; set; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

        public OrdersPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
   
            MyItem Item = new MyItem();
            Item.PickupNo = "123456789";
            MyCollection.Add(Item);
            BindingContext = this;
        }

}
```

This will give you an output like this:

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you for the help. But I figured it out. I want **number** to be a normal property in the class not a property of the ItemSource. So in the way iw as doing it **number** was considered as a property of the item source which is not the case so nothing was shown.I solved it by giving the content page a name and then bind the **Text** attribute {Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ordersPage}, Path=Number}